# Carousel Automatic Transition that slides from the right

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML code that is different from many of the ones I found on stackoverflow I think so using their answers did not work for me.

I have a carousel with left and right buttons that allow users to go to the previous and next images. However, in the mean-time, I would like my carousel to transition automatically every 3 seconds sliding from the right (so image 2 will slide in from the right to replace image 1). I have tried doing this in my JS file but while it does transition every 3 seconds (without the sliding part), when you click on a button it somehow speeds up the carousel (also the back button doesn't seem to work when I add the automatic transition even though without it, it works perfectly fine).

**My HTML code:**

```
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 1</h3>
      <p>Caption 1 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 2</h3>
      <p>Caption 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 2</h3>
      <p>Caption 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <!-- <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> -->
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="interactions.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

My JS Code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated my JS to include this variable but it doesn't work when it's within showSlides function, but it works when it's outside and set in global environment.

```
var timer = setInterval( function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000 );
```

What function do I need to add to make this automatic transition work and to make it slide from right to left? Or do I simply edit one of my existing functions?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the timer in your JS? Normally what is happening here is that you need to clear and reset the timer (interval, whatnot) everytime you trigger the action.  A lot of the time, the timer slips in and is nested into the main code so when you click forward at 1.5 seconds you then have two timers waiting to progress, one in the next 3 seconds and the original timer waiting to finish in 1.5 seconds.  And then this starts snow ball as more timers are created but none of them were destroyed.

Comment: Making the slides move from left to right (or any direction) is a whole other can of worms -- what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Set an interval and assign it to a variable...

```
var timer = setInterval( function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000 );
```

In your code be sure to clear the Interval and reset it...

```
function showSlides(n) {
  clearInterval( timer );
  ...
  timer = setInterval( function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000 );
}
```

**Update:**

I tried it again, but this time using a timeout.  When the showSlides() function executes it clears the timer and then triggers the whole process again after the defined time.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

var timer;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout( function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 5000 );
}
```

```css
.dot, .slideNav a{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideNav{
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.dot{
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dot.active{ background-color: black; }

.carousel-caption{ 
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding: 5px 5%;
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 1</h3>
      <p>Caption 1 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webcontent/@web/documents/media/2016-photocontest-yosemite-w-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 2</h3>
      <p>Caption 2 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Caption 3</h3>
      <p>Caption 3 text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="slideNav" style="text-align:center">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can put timer = setInterval... and it will automatically transition every 3 seconds.. but doing clearInterval at the beginning messes up the entire HTML/CSS so nothing but the 3 dots show up and when I put the line in other areas of the showSlides function, it just stops after the first transition?

Comment: I tinkered around this a bit and I tried a `timeout` instead of the interval and it produced more regular results.  In regards to the images sliding in and out, that's a whole different topic.